# ffmpeg: Low framerate when capturing with -vcodec mjpeg but not with -vcodec copy

Tags: ffmpeg, mjpeg

I'm trying to capture video from a webcam, and I find that when I use the `-vcodec copy` option, it works really well (far better than any other software I've tried).  However, I'd like my files to be a bit smaller, and it seems that every attempt I make to compress the video leads to extremely jumpy video.  If, for example, I switch the output vcodec to `mjpeg`, it changes from reporting 15 fps to reporting between 3 and 4 fps.  Am I doing something wrong??  Here is the call with `-vcodec copy`:

```
ffmpeg -y -f dshow -vcodec mjpeg -s 1184x656 -framerate 25 -i video="HD 720P Webcam" -vcodec copy test.avi
```

-- which gets me 15 fps.  But if I change to `mjpeg`, I get only 3-4 fps:

```
ffmpeg -y -f dshow -vcodec mjpeg -s 1184x656 -framerate 25 -i video="HD 720P Webcam" -vcodec mjpeg test.avi
```

Experimental attempts to put `-framerate 25` or `-r 25` before `test.avi` also does nothing to help the situation.  I'm not getting any smoother video when experimenting with `mpeg4` or `libx264` either.  Only the `copy` option gives me smooth video (btw I'm filming my hands playing a piano, so there is a lot of fast motion in the videos).

Help!!!!  And thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why the framerate drops so much, but you could try a 2 pass approach where you first record it using -vcodec copy (as you pasted in the question)

```
ffmpeg -y -f dshow -vcodec mjpeg -s 1184x656 -framerate 25 -i video="HD 720P Webcam" -vcodec copy test.avi
```

Then transcode it into mjpeg once it's done (something like this):

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi -vcodec mjpeg test.mjpeg
```

note: I haven't actually tested any of the above command lines.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion bluemonki!  Now ffmpeg reports that it's giving me 30fps, but the video that is produced has exactly the same qualities as with the other method: there are huge gaps (even over half a second in one place) with only one frame, and no more than about 6 frames in any given second...  (The video with the approach in the original post also came out looking like this).  All help v much appreciated!

Comment: The other examples I've seen involve using `-r` as @Mulvya suggests and potentially using `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps` which should force ffmpeg to the system clock for timestamps to prevent it getting confused by the variable framerate video

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your webcam is outputting a variable frame rate stream. Try the below on one of your `copy` captured files.

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi -vcodec libx264 -r 30 test.mp4
```

(You should avoid capturing to AVI, use MKV instead)